# Possible to get the magic mouse 2 touchpad working with ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, magic-mouse

I've managed to set up the magic mouse 2 with Ubuntu over bluetooth, but it is only recognising it as a two-button mouse. Using the touchpad over xev doesn't show anything being picked up.

Is it possible to get Ubuntu to recognise any touchpad commands of this device? Could anyone point me in the direction of any useful resources to try to debug this?

Comment: any luck with this? in the same boat a couple of months later...

Answer (score 6):

I too got myself a Magic Mouse 2 about 6 weeks ago. You can teach Linux to recognise the Magic Mouse 2 and load the hid_magicmouse module (as it would for the original Magic Mouse and Trackpad) by modifying the udev and modprobe configs. The touch protocols have changed from the MM1 so the MM2 is still just a 2-button device at this time. In my spare time, I am working on decoding how the driver should set up the MM2 but it is a slow process. I have documented what I have so far on a Github project at https://github.com/biggreenogre/mm2. I'm working with Ubuntu Trusty but, since this is in the kernel, it should apply to most recent releases and distros.

Regards,

Drew

Comment: Would be eager to hear if you have updates on this.

Comment: update would be great or an alternative @thunderboltz